# How can I set a border in alignment with other borders

Tags: html, css

I have a theme with following code:

```
    table.alt {
        border-collapse: separate;
    }

        table.alt tbody tr td {
            border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-top-width: 0;
        }

            table.alt tbody tr td:first-child {
                border-left-width: 1px;
            }

        table.alt tbody tr:first-child td {
            border-top-width: 1px;
        }

        table.alt thead {
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        table.alt tfoot {
            border-top: 0;
        }
```

When I add my css to my html, the borders aren't aligned correctly. My code is:

```
table.alt tr th.rightAlignBorderLeft {
    text-align: right;
    border-left: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
}
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I don't want to set border-collapse to collapse, because changing my default theme code may mess up my pages.
How can I fix this?

Edit:
Here's my (new) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ru1923mf/1/

Comment: can you share some html? It's hard without it...

Comment: thanks for the answer. http://sudrap.org/paste/text/392202/

Comment: @nikel Can you please post the **relevant** HTML, here in the question?

Comment: @nikel Did you try border-left: none; border-right: none;? (Use none and not 0 and also not border-left-width)

Comment: can you please post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#run)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ru1923mf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this. I found the answer here: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-can-i-set-a-border-in-alignment-with-other-borders/